# Importing package python

Tags: python, python-import

Pretty new to python but trying to write a reusable package for some data processing I've been doing a lot recently.

My project I'm wanting to structure like

```
src/
    mypackage/*.py
    test/
      test-type1/*.py
      test-type2/*.py
      ...
```

Each 'test-type' will have multiple scripts underneath it. My issue is when I try to import mypackage like in the root directory it explodes. I'm curious what a good way to handle this is? I can't just use relative paths since I get an error

```
attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
If a test file was in the root directory I could just do. With the change in directories I can't do that without getting the relative import error.

```
import mypackage.{file}
```

Edit2:
Example of code of one of my tests. Folder structure

```
rl/
  __init__.py
  callbacks/
       __init__.py
       checkpoint.py
       earlystop.py
       progress.py
  training/
       __init__.py
       train.py
tests/
    cartpole-v1/
         train.py
```

''' Code

```
import gym
import torch
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pole_actor import PoleActor
from ...rl.training import train
from ...rl.callbacks import Checkpoint, EarlyStop, ProgressBarCallback

def a2c(env: gym.Env):   
   actor = PoleActor(batch_size=50,max_memory=500,optimizer=torch.optim.Adam,lr=3e-4)
   rewards = train(env,actor,3000,callbacks=[
      Checkpoint(save_path='models/pole-callback.ach5',patience=100),
      EarlyStop(patience=500,delay=1000),
      #Need a better way of selecting the 'best' model, ideally we should always get a good model out of here
      ProgressBarCallback()
   ])

   smoothed = pd.Series.rolling(pd.Series(rewards),10).mean()
   plt.plot()
   plt.xlabel('Episodes')
   plt.ylabel('Reward')
   plt.plot(rewards)
   plt.plot(smoothed)
   plt.show(block=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")
    a2c(env)
```

Comment: can you share how are you importing in root directory?

Comment: Try creating \___init\___.py files in the directories. That will make the directory a package

Comment: @gsb22 added how I did it in root directory, pretty basic

Comment: @saxo `__init__.py` files are no longer required to make a directory a package. See [PEP420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/). Chase, can you show us how you're running you code? Relative import only make sense if you executing a module as part of a package (e.g. via `python -m mypackage.test.test_type1.module`). You can't use relative import if you're running your code as a top-level module (e.g. via `python test-type1/module.py`).

Comment: @saxo If I do that, added in test-type, test, src, and it already existed in mypackage I still get the same error with relative import or absolute import.

Comment: @Brian hey brian I brought in my code to show what stuff looks like

Answer (score 0):

You could use these lines of code before importing the library:

```
import os,sys,inspect
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)
sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir)
```

this code will import the packages from the parent directory instead of the current directory.